# Add a textview at the end of the gridview for Load More Images

Tags: android

I have a problem that, I want to add a textView or a button at the bottom of the gridview. But I am failed to achieve this, I had tried a linearlayout after the gridview in the xml but there was not a successful attempt. Please help me regarding to this problem that I want a textview in the bottom of the gridview.

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:pax="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.shopzilla.android.common"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/main_Linear_Layout" android:background="#ffffff">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:background="#191970" android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/linear_Header_Layout">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/img_logo" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:src="@drawable/bizratelogo2"></ImageView>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:background="@drawable/list_view_icon" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" android:id="@+id/btn_searchresult_list"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn_RefineSearch" android:textSize="15dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/refine_search_btn" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linear_Layout_Search" android:background="@drawable/bluebg">
        <EditText android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" android:layout_width="300dip" android:layout_height="30dip" android:background="@drawable/search_bar_bg" android:layout_marginLeft="7dip" android:paddingLeft="30dip" android:id="@+id/txt_search_grid" android:singleLine="true" android:clickable="true" android:focusable="false"></EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linear_Header_Layout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linear_load"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:background="#E4E4E4" android:layout_height="265dip">
        <GridView 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Search_Result_Grid" android:background="#E4E4E4" android:focusable="true" android:verticalSpacing="10dp">
        </GridView>
       </LinearLayout> 
       <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linear_load"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="35dip">
       <TextView
       android:id="@+id/lbl_load"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Load More" android:textSize="18dip" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="115dip"></TextView>
       </LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/widget3" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                >
                    <com.shopzilla.android.common.Toolbar 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        pax:tab_id="tab1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom"/> 
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you need to make a dynamic greed view

Comment: just elaborate pls where do you want that button placed? outside below the grid? like your linearLoad layout is placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `TextView` inside the `GridView` tag.

### -

**UPDATE** :

You have in your XML this structure:

```
    <LinearLayout>
        <GridView></GridView>
    </LinearLayout> 
    <LinearLayou>
        <TextView></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Make it looks like this:

```
    <LinearLayout>
        <GridView></GridView>
        <TextView></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Make sure that:

- LinearLayout: `layout_width="fill_parent"`
- GridView: `layout_width="wrap_content"`
- TextView: `layout_width="wrap_content"`

Good Luck !

Comment: we can not add textview in gridview tag, so please give me the accurate results.

Comment: thanks for the answer 2rk but by this implementation textview displayed at the bottom of layout and screen and Gridview scrolls as default, but I want to add a textview at the last of the gridview as when scrolling ends.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:pax="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.shopzilla.android.common"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/main_Linear_Layout"
  android:background="#ffffff">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#191970"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:id="@+id/linear_Header_Layout">
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/img_logo"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
      android:src="@drawable/bizratelogo2"></ImageView>
    <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
      android:background="@drawable/list_view_icon"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
      android:id="@+id/btn_searchresult_list"></Button>
    <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/btn_RefineSearch"
      android:textSize="15dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/refine_search_btn"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dip"></Button>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linear_Layout_Search"
    android:background="@drawable/bluebg">
    <EditText
      android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
      android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
      android:layout_width="300dip"
      android:layout_height="30dip"
      android:background="@drawable/search_bar_bg"
      android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
      android:paddingLeft="30dip"
      android:id="@+id/txt_search_grid"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:focusable="false"></EditText>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear_Header_Layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linear_load"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:background="#E4E4E4"
      android:layout_height="265dip">
      <GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/Search_Result_Grid"
        android:background="#E4E4E4"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linear_load"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="35dip">
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_load"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load More"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="115dip"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/widget3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <com.shopzilla.android.common.Toolbar
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      pax:tab_id="tab1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't really understand what you really need, but as i understand this you want the "load more" layout to be at the bottom of the grid and the grid to fill the height to it.
You achieve that by setting the grids height to fill_parent and its weight to 1.

Comment: Problem remains same after applying fill parent and weight=1 in grid view, please provide me another solution for that.